# word add in cached and not able to remove it

Tags: vba, ms-word

there was originally an add-in installed for word, under the path

> D:\User\UserName\AppData\Microsoft\Word\Startup\addin.dot

it is working fine, and it add to Word menu with a name addin_2017. Since it is already 2021, we figured its better to update the menu name, so we changed the name to addin_v2 instead. However, when we place the updated addin.dot into the folder, both name showed up in the Word add-in menu. addin_2017, and addin_v2. I am wondering if there are anything cached somewhere.

I have also tried to use VBA code to remove all the add-in, but when I copy the file back to the STARTUP folder, there are two items in the menu still.

[image]

Comment: Did you delete the original file from the startup folder? If all you've done is change the name and copy it back to the folder there will be two files for Word to load.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt yes i deleted the original file before i paste the new one in there. there is only one single file in there, but now its showing the NEW and OLD menu for some reason

Comment: "I am wondering if there are anything cached somewhere" - no, Word doesn't cache add-in templates. It simply loads them at Startup. Which version of Word are you using? The file name for the add-in template suggests Word 2003.

Comment: i am using Word 2016, I have tried many ways, as I said, the name was addin_2017, and i have set the menu caption to addin_v2, but when i paste it into the startup folder and both addin_v2 and addin_2017 shows up @TimothyRylatt

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65791592/edit) and add a screenshot showing how these show up in the ribbon.

Comment: Also go to the Developer tab and click on the 'Document Template' button to display the Templates and Add-ins dialog. This will show you all the global templates that are loaded and give you their file paths.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt i have updated the image

Comment: @TimothyRylatt i have checked the templates, it is correct, but the macro is somehow caching the old menu name

Comment: Your basic problem is that you are still using an add-in created for Word 97-2003 in Office 2016. The long-term solution is to replace the add-in replacing the menus with a custom ribbon tab. I haven't worked with O2003 in over a decade so I can't provide you with an immediate solution.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt so i will have to make a new "addin" in a way? like building a new one?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt because i will need to deploy it to different machines, setting it up one by one is not the best option

Comment: Yes that is your best option for a long term solution. Your current code is out of date by at least 5 versions of Office. Presumably you already have a means of deploying your current add-in which you can continue to use.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt i will look into that, but i guess it will require more time for me to develop the whole thing. Trying to find a way to run it the current way

Comment: Have you also tried renaming Normal.dotm? In the distant recesses of my memory I recall that menus could get 'stuck' there. If the menu is still there when there are no files in the Startup folder it would suggest that it has got attached to Normal.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I just took a look at Normal.dotm, but the file is empty and the macro is also empty as well, i don't see anything that i can change there

Comment: Looking at it won't tell you anything useful. I've already given you the steps to take to identify if that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt i actaully tried to delete the normal.dotm but issue still exist

Comment: And are the menus still there when there is nothing in the startup folder?

Comment: only one of the menu exist after i removed the file from startup (the one with the updated name)

Comment: And does the menu still exist if you remove the add-in from the Startup folder and rename Normal?

Answer (score 1):

Looking back at some (very old) Wd2003 projects the method that I used was to have two separate routines for deleting and creating menus. These were called when the add-in was loaded and unloaded, e.g.

```
Public Sub AutoExec()

  DeleteMenu
  CreateMenu

End Sub

Public Sub AutoExit()

  DeleteMenu

End Sub

Public Sub DeleteMenu()
   Dim cbc As Office.CommandBarControl

   For Each cbc In Application.CommandBars("Menu Bar")
      If cbc.Caption = "AddinV2" Or cbc.Caption = "Addin2017" Then cbc.Delete
   Next cbc
End Sub
```

It is obvious from your investigations that the rogue menu exists in the addin. One option to remove it is to:

1. Create a new template
2. Export all the code modules from the existing addin
3. Import the modules into the new template.

This should be seen as only a (very) temporary measure until you have created a new add-in with a custom ribbon tab.

Comment: thank you for looking it up. For DeleteMenu, do you do something like 
`Dim A as Addin For Each A in Application.Addins A.Installed = Not A.Installed next` because I have look up my entire code again and again, there is no such word with Addin2017, but it is still creating this menu

Comment: why would you delete the menu at autoExit?

Comment: @kownowl - you delete the menu in AutoExit because the add-in is being unloaded. It prevents the behavior that you are experiencing.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply, i am gonna give it a try later, and see if it works.

Comment: @kownowl - Don't be tempted to just drag and drop the modules into the new template. Exporting the modules has the effect of 'cleaning' them, removing any hidden corruption.